# DataGridView - DefaultCellStyle, rows and columns priority

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

In C#, in DataGridView I want to set the BackColor property for the first row and first column. And the cell from first row and first column, should have property from first column, not row - but it does.

For example: (table 3 x 3); 'X' - property for first row, 'Y' - property for first column, 'a' - default property

- should be:

**Y** X X
Y a a
Y a a

- but is:

**X** X X
Y a a
Y a a

There is no matter which property I set first:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
```

or:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
```

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably something internal to DataGridViews, where row styles override column styles either explicitly or because row styles are applied on top of column styles.

In addition to setting default styles for the first row and first column, try setting the first cell's style directly, which will override ANY default, whether for row or column:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here's a reference to the documentation which confirms @KeithS 's assumption:

> With the DataGridView control, you can specify default cell styles for the entire control and for specific columns and rows. These defaults **filter down from the control level to the column level, then to the row level, then to the cell level**. If a particular DataGridViewCellStyle property is not set at the cell level, the default property setting at the row level is used. If the property is also not set at the row level, the default column setting is used. Finally, if the property is also not set at the column level, the default DataGridView setting is used.

Found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-default-cell-styles-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)