# RowsAdded Event made a Strange behavior when changing back color of row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I bind a `DataGridView` to a (List of 'Payment' objects) collection, I am using `RowsAdded` Event to Change the back color of the row depending on the status of the payment.
I am using (`row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`) to change the back color, But If I changed the color of the First row, then the color of the second row will be changed also, even though I did NOT change its back color.
and I don't want to change its back color to (white) because there are some columns that have their own colors.

```
private void dgvPayment_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = dgvPayment.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Payment  lPayment = row.DataBoundItem as Payment;
            if (lPayment != null)
                if (lPayment.IsLocked)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
                    row.ReadOnly = true;
                }
        }
```

how to solve this ?

you can download the source code for [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/UploadFile/houssam11350/11232012083215AM/rowsaddedproblem.zip) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that when I put the backColor to white, the whole row will become white,I don't want this , because there are a column(s) which have its own backColor.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673894/datagridview-defaultcellstyle-rows-and-columns-priority) (datagridview-defaultcellstyle-rows-and-columns-priority) :

> It's probably something internal to DataGridViews, where row styles
>   override column styles either explicitly or because row styles are
>   applied on top of column styles.
>
> In addition to setting default styles for the first row and first
>   column, try setting the first cell's style directly, which will
>   override ANY default, whether for row or column.

So I Solved it like this;

```
private void dgvPayment_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int index = e.RowIndex; index <= e.RowIndex + e.RowCount - 1; index++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dgvPayment.Rows[index];
                Payment lPayment = row.DataBoundItem as Payment;
                if (lPayment != null && lPayment.IsLocked)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
                    row.ReadOnly = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle = null;
                    row.ReadOnly = false;
                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The rows added event behaves somewhat unpredictably - for this sort of grid manipulation it is usually better to use other events.

In this case use the `CellFormatting` event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dgvPayment.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Payment  lPayment = row.DataBoundItem as Payment;
    if (lPayment != null && lPayment.IsLocked)
    {                
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
    }
    else
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: He does not have to change the way he is updating the rows. Only the fact that his logic meant that it looked like this was a problem for a particular state (i.e. selection of row one) - it wasn't; you need to set the default cell style _each time_ you want it updated.

Comment: @Killercam I tried your solution and it didn't always work when using the RowsUpdated event. In certain situations (possibly when you have rows after the last row with IsLocked) those rows are incorrectly coloured.

Comment: From my tests it works fine. As long as the event is fired - which it is it should always update the colors correctly. Fair play for testing my solution. All the best and have a good weekend. :]

Comment: thanks for your replay . this will make the color of all cells in the row is white, but some columns should be in LightPink Color. I Posted the answer .